# How to best test what environment the server is running in?

Tags: sql-server

Where I work the production databases are backed up nightly and restored to dev, test, and QA environments. When running any of the programs in non-production environments, to avoid making changes we don't want to make in production, such as sending real users email, our programs test the environments using a combination of internally parsing the command line, and calling an SQL user function. The function selects @@SERVERNAME, then parses the result looking for specific strings ie. if the ServerName contains "-PROD-", it is a production server.

The problem is the hardware group is implementing a high availability project so if a server fails @@SERVERNAME will return the name of the backup server. I am looking at extending the current logic to account for whatever the fail-over server names will be, but I was hoping there was a better way to test the environment than parsing text for static strings.

Comment: Down voters, what is wrong with the question?

Comment: Not my downvote but there are so many possibilities here. You could have something like papercut running on your dev server so no emails go through to the outside world. You could have something in the config file of the applications. There are a zillion ways to deal with this kind of thing.

Comment: @SeanLange, Thanks for the response, but not sending email to real users is not the only consideration. Both inside the programs, and in SQL stored procedure actions are dependent on the environment. Things such as writing summaries to other tables, creating reports on production servers, alerting users to actions performed, etc. I was hoping there was some property in SQL that I am not aware of that is more reliable than testing for specific text.

Comment: Until I can find a less error prone way to perform this check my plan is to change the user function to query for the cluster_name from sys.availability_group_listeners. This will return what @@servername is returning now regardless of the actual machine running the current instance. None of the existing text parsing and comparisons will need changing.

Comment: Is the SQL server the right place to store this setting (by server name or otherwise)? You could instead use settings deployed to each program environment to configure the program as to how it should behave (e.g. web.config transformations). Here you can include multiple steps to ensure no mail gets out including perhaps configuring a mail server setting to a dummy one.

Comment: The main program is a VB6 program. Using an .ini file was a thought, but if I am launching 1 instance that points to production, and a second instance that points to QA it gets complicated to make on file do that. The method that has been in place for years is to let the user function on the server parse it's instance name and return the environment. So inside the program before anything is done that needs to know the environment fn_IsProductionEnv is called. So it is the location of the database that decides the environment.

Answer (score 1):

Store a setting in a database that is separate from your application database(s) then read that setting as-needed using a function. When your application runs in production, you'll get the production values. When your application runs in Development, you'll get the development values.

The nice thing about this is you can store all kinds of values and easily get to them from your SPROCS, PowerShell or whatever front end you have.

```
CREATE DATABASE SETTINGSDB
GO

USE SETTINGSDB
GO

-- A table to hold key/value pairs
CREATE TABLE MYSETTINGS
(
    SettingName VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ,
    SettingValue VARCHAR(500)
)
GO

-- On DEVELOPMENT SERVER, run this
INSERT INTO MYSETTINGS
VALUES ('ENVIRONMENT', 'DEV'),
        ('SOME_SETTING', 'True')

-- On PRODUCTION SERVER, run this
INSERT INTO MYSETTINGS
VALUES ('ENVIRONMENT', 'PROD'),
        ('SOME_SETTING', 'False')

GO

-- A function to pull key/value pairs.
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetEnvVar( @SettingName VARCHAR(50) )
RETURNS VARCHAR(500)
AS
    BEGIN
        RETURN (SELECT SettingValue FROM SETTINGSDB.dbo.MYSETTINGS WHERE SettingName = @SettingName)
    END
GO
```

Once you are setup, you can then check the value, and it will be different between DEV/PROD. For example:

```
-- Then use these values:
USE YourApplicationDatabaseNameHere
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE SampleApplicationSprocThatSendsEmail 
    @EmailAddress VARCHAR(50),
    @Subject VARCHAR(50)
AS

    IF (dbo.GetEnvVar('ENVIRONMENT') = 'PROD' )
    BEGIN
        -- Only Executes in Production
        -- TODO: SEND THE EMAIL
    END ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- Only Executes in Development
        PRINT 'Send email to ' + @EmailAddress
    END
```

Comment: I actually like this idea, and suggested that, but the rest of the team for some reason didn't like it.

Comment: My guess is they didn't like it because they didn't like having a "whole database for one value". I posted another answer below that similar but simpler.

Comment: meh, I delete the other answer because it's basically what you're planning on doing already.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding all possible objects that might cause harm or annoyance to some unknown number of targets (mailboxes, files, databases, etc...) why not just isolate the dev/test environment at the network layer? Put them in an isolated network/subnet where only inbound is permitted, all outbound gets blocked or rerouted. It's hard to know for sure you've gotten every single endpoint. For example, what happens if your admins add more secondaries for additional protection and read-only queries?

We used SQL Server's trace replay capabilities regularly for many years for service pack, upgrade (app and db), regression, cross-workload and other tests. Every so often we'll have some smart, highly motivated new team member (new hire or transfer) who would write scripts or "cleansing" apps to scrub the trace files and databases so the tests can be run on his/her workstation. Every single one of them will learn that's a bad idea, sometimes in a very, very hard way (e.g. re-index a clustered index on a highly volatile 2billion row table in mid-morning).

Blocking at the network layer has the added benefit of minimal prep/setup work for each test run plus you can have an identical setup as prod. When you encounter bugs or regressions, you have a few items less to check.

Comment: Good suggestion but it won't work. In particular before a new release we select a few actual users and they do dual entry using the production and QA environments. The difference is only the database server passed into the program via the command-line.